# How can I concat observables, but get value only from last of them?

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is the example of the thing i have in my angular app:

```
concat(
  obs1$,
  obs2$,
  obs3$
)
.subscribe() // Output: obs1$ value, obs2$ value, obs3$ value. Basically normal concat behaviour
```

This is what i am trying to achieve:

```
concatLast(
  obs1$,
  obs2$,
  obs3$
)
.subscribe() // Output: obs3$ value
```

I don't want to use `skip()`, `takeLast()`, `switchMap()` end etc, cause it too much repeating code and doesn't look good when there will be like 5+ obs. So i want to find universal solution.
Maybe there is some RxJs operator or some tricks that allows you to do such things

Comment: The use case is not clear enough, why don't use the obs3$ directly if you need its value only? Could you please clarify your question with more details?

Comment: @Amer imo its pretty clear what the author wants. Looking onto different streams - it is not know what observable will emit last. Therefore you have to wait for all observables and only take the last emitted. That can be obs1$, obs2$ or obs3$. Your solution doesnt handle obs1$ or obs2$ to emit last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [last](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/last) operator to filter the last item emitted by the source observable.

```js
const { timer, concat } = rxjs;
const { mapTo, last } = rxjs.operators

const source1$ = timer(0).pipe(mapTo(1))
const source2$ = timer(50).pipe(mapTo(2))
const source3$ = timer(100).pipe(mapTo(3))

const result$ = concat(source1$, source2$, source3$).pipe(
  last()
)

result$.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

If you reuse this piece of code several times in your code you can avoid even more repeating code by putting this logic into a custom operator (`concatLast`)

```js
const { timer, concat } = rxjs;
const { mapTo, last } = rxjs.operators

const source1$ = timer(0).pipe(mapTo(1))
const source2$ = timer(50).pipe(mapTo(2))
const source3$ = timer(100).pipe(mapTo(3))

const concatLast = (...sources) => concat(...sources).pipe(
  last()
)

const result$ = concatLast(source1$, source2$, source3$)

result$.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combinelatest will emit both `a` and `b` every time when one of them changes. a) will emit every 10sec, and b) will emit every 3 seconds.

```js
const a = stream('a', 10000, 10, 'partial');
const b = stream('b', 3000, 10, 'partial');

combineLatest(a, b).subscribe(fullObserver('latest'));
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/combine-latest-flsp5m?file=main.ts

And in Angular it could be something like this

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  mapResult: any;
  from$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  to$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  searchTerm$ = combineLatest(this.from$, this.to$);

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchTerm$
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        switchMap((terms) => of(terms))
      )
      .subscribe((term: any) => (this.mapResult = term));
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/combinelatest-angular-army-qecyev

But using `of()` is not recommended. So here is a bit newer example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular Combine Lates With Interval Example';
  subOne: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  subTwo: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  counterOne: number = 0;
  counterTwo: number = 0;
  data: [number, number];

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.subOne.next(++this.counterOne);
    }, 2000);

    setInterval(() => {
      this.subTwo.next(++this.counterTwo);
    }, 5000);

    combineLatest(this.subOne, this.subTwo).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-combine-lates-with-interval-example-9vvqz7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts